# Force all capitals in NSTextField (Cocoa)

Tags: cocoa, nstextfield, capitalization

Is there a way to force capitals in a NSTextField?

I want to create a text field for typing in Post Codes, and I want all post codes entered to use capital letters.

e.g. N1 3ET instead of: n1 3et

Also, I am using a regular expression, which only accepts capitals (I know very little about regular expressions, so I'm not keen on modifying it)

Thank you!

Michael

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could give the NSTextField a [delegate](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextField_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000128-SW10) with something along the lines of:

```
- (void)controlTextDidChange:(NSNotification *)aNotification{
    NSText *fieldEditor = [[aNotification userInfo] objectForKey:@"NSFieldEditor"];
    [fieldEditor setString:[[fieldEditor string] uppercaseString]];
}
```

It should catch text changing notifications and uppercase the text.

Comment: This does only work when editing at the end of the text field but not when the cursor is in the middle of the text.

Answer (score 2):

Anq's answer works well, but in the Cocoa world, this is what [NSFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) was created for. It's about the same amount of work and can be easily ported to any part of your project (or to any other project).

See also the [Data Formatting Programming Guide For Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/DataFormatting.html).

Answer (score 2):

Swift solution. The class that is the NSTextField delegate should contain:

```
override func controlTextDidChange(obj: NSNotification) 
{
    if let info = obj.userInfo, text = info["NSFieldEditor"] as? NSText,
        string = text.string
    {
        text.string = string.uppercaseString
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do the same thing as Anq's answer in Swift

```
override func controlTextDidChange(obj: NSNotification!) {
    //Make the username all caps to match the PM
    var infoDictionary:Dictionary = obj.userInfo! as Dictionary
    var text:NSText = infoDictionary["NSFieldEditor"] as NSText;
    text.string = text.string.uppercaseString
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hook NStexfield to delegate in IB than:

```
- (void)controlTextDidChange:(NSNotification *)aNotification{
  editField = [aNotification object];
  NSString* value = [editField stringValue];
  [editField setStringValue:[value uppercaseString]];
  //NSLog(@"editField%@", editField.stringValue);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem I had with the solutions above is that when I made a change to the textfield in the UI, the cursor would move to the end of the string. So if I had a string in the textfield, like this

[VCOUVER     ]

I would place my cursor at 1:

[V|COUVER     ]

and type the lower case letter 'a', this would happen:

[VACOUVER|     ]

not noticing this, I would type the 'n' and get:

[VACOUVERN|    ]

crap... OK, here's my fix:

```
-(void)controlTextDidChange:(NSNotification *)obj {
    if([obj.object isEqualTo:self.locationTextField]) {
        NSText *fieldEditor = [[obj userInfo] objectForKey:@"NSFieldEditor"];
        NSRange rng = [fieldEditor selectedRange];
        [fieldEditor setString:[[fieldEditor string] uppercaseString]];
        [fieldEditor setSelectedRange:rng];
    }
}
```

That is, before applying the uppercase, grab the position of the cursor, apply the uppercase, and then put the cursor back.